# Prove that $sgn(\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2) = sgn(\sigma_1)sgn(\sigma_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

Lete $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that the transformation $$sgn: S_n \rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$$

(where $S_n$ is the set of all permutations of the integers in the set $\{1,...,n\}$),given by $\sigma \mapsto sgn(\sigma)$, $\sigma \in S_n$, is a group homomorphism, i.e. the following equality holds:

$$sgn(\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2) = sgn(\sigma_1)sgn(\sigma_2)$$

Def.(sgn) : Let $\sigma \in S_n$ be a permutation that can be expressed as l transpositions. Then $sgn(\sigma) := (-1)^l$

My attempt:

Since every permutation $\sigma$ can be expressed as the product of a given number of transpositions, I have the following:

Let $\sigma_1 = \tau_1 \circ \tau_2 \circ .... \circ \tau_l$ and $\sigma_2 = \tau_1 \circ \tau_2 \circ .... \circ \tau_k$. Then it follows that $\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2 = \tau_1 \circ \tau_2 \circ .... \circ \tau_l \circ \tau_1 \circ \tau_2 \circ .... \circ \tau_k$. Now I'm not exactly sure how to go from here and whether my approach is correct. I kind of doubt it, since I need $l + k$ transpositions to derive $\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2$, but the sum of those could easily be greater than $n$, right? In case my approach was correct thus far, how can I show that the equality holds, could I case cases depending on whether l and k are even or odd to prove the equality?

Comment: How is $sgn$ defined? As long as that is unclear it is impossible to prove that it is a grouphomomorphism.

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hard part of $sgn$ is to show that *any* transposition decomposition of a permutation will always have an odd number or and even number of transposition, regardless of how you decompose it--you can have as many transpositions as you want, even more than $n$ transpositions. So you assign permutations with an even number of transpositions 1 and permutations with an odd number of transpositions the number -1.

Now that you have established this *well definedness* property of *sgn* the problem becomes much easier.  You can consider the 4 possible cases when l and k are even and odd respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We actually did prove that in a lecture, but I didn't really know whether I needed to apply this here. I think I still haven't completely understood the notion of transposition. From what I understand is that every permutation can be expressed through a number of transposition starting with the identity permutation. Is that correct? Is every product of transpositions applied on the ID or can any random starting permutation be used?

Comment: You just need to convince yourself that every cyclic permutation can be written as a product of transpositions.  Here is how: (a b c d e f) = (a b)(b c)(c d)(d e)(e f).  Now given any permutation, you write it down as in a decomposition of cyclic permutations, each of which you can write out in transpositions.  Just remember, a transposition is a function that swaps two objects.  (a b) is the transposition that gives b when given a, and gives a when given b.